# Child Relationship Query not working with API

Tags: api, query

I have Accounts and InteractionsReferences.

Trying to query something like this (formatted because I'm using GET query:

```
SELECT+Account.Name+,(SELECT+Interaction_References__r.Id+FROM+Interaction_References__r)+FROM+Account+ORDER+BY+CreatedDate+DESC+LIMIT+10
```

But I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "\nInteraction_References__r.Id FROM Interaction_References__r) FROM ERROR at Row:1:Column:64 Didn't understand relationship 'Interaction_References__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_TYPE"
}
```

However, when looking at the field in Salesforce, I see this, which makes it seem like I am calling it the right way:

[image: child relationship name]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within each SELECT, you reference the field relative to the FROM object. In other words, it should just be Id (presumably); the same is true for `Account.Name`, it should just be `Name`. Also, if this is a managed field, you may need to prefix the relationship name with the namespace:

```
SELECT Name,
  (SELECT Id FROM AIM__Interaction_References__r) 
FROM Account ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 10
```

The primary use for the __r.Field convention is when you're going from child to parent records:

```
SELECT AIM__Account__r.Name
FROM AIM__Account__c
```